# Flutter- Update Multiple Widgets Simultaneously with a Timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView with a bunch of widgets inside that display a countdown. I managed to create a Timer for each widget to update every second, **but my goal is to have 1 master clock** to manage them all.

But the thing is, I don't know how to access my widgets all at once from another script.
I suspect this has something to do with State Management (I'm new to flutter, and I was advised to put this subject off for the start).

The code I have so far:

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(seconds: 1),
  (timer) {
    setState(() {
      // magically update every widget inside ListView here..
    });
  },
```

Would really like to hear your ideas guys,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code for your reference to do the same:

```
// Create a list to store the countdown values for each widget
List<int> countdownValues = [10, 20, 30]; // Example initial values

// Inside your build method
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: countdownValues.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Use countdownValues[index] to display the countdown in each widget
    return YourWidget(countdownValue: countdownValues[index]);
  },
),

// Set up the master clock timer
Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(seconds: 1),
  (timer) {
    setState(() {
      // Update the countdown values for each widget
      for (int i = 0; i < countdownValues.length; i++) {
        countdownValues[i]--;
      }
    });
  },
),
```

You can see, here the `countdownValues` list stores the countdown values for each widget in the ListView. The `itemBuilder` inside the ListView's `builder` creates widgets based on the countdown values in the list.
Then, inside the Timer callback, the countdown values are decremented, and `setState` is called to trigger a rebuild of the ListView with the updated countdown values. As a result, all the widgets will be updated simultaneously using the master clock.

Hopefully, this is what you were looking for! Keep Fluttering!